# jQuery which selector for sub-elements?

Tags: jquery

I can't figure out which selector to use to get the items listed in a sub menu.

1. List item
2. List Item
3. List item

   1. A
   2. B
   3. C

I want to paginate a list using Next/Prev but the sub menu won't show up.  I want to show 5 items at a time, but when you hit next, you don't get the sub-list returned.

And the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/saltcod/bXKsZ/1/

Thanks

Comment: You're so close, remember you can select `li li` to get sub-list items of course hiding `li` hides all `li`'s sub and main

Comment: You're HTML is not valid, the submenu `ul` should be inside a `li`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is going to hide all your sub LI's also.

```
$('ul li:gt(4)').hide();
```

Assume main UL id=list, hide only children LI's

```
 $('#list > li:gt(4)').hide();
```

EDIT: same issue with next/prev . Use a parent ID to define children, not `UL` since submenus also have `UL`

Answer (score 1):

Use the `space` char to indicate a descendant node.

`$('ancestor descendant')`

http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/

If you want a direct child node only, use `>`

`$('parent>immediateChild')`

http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/